# Expectation value of non-interacting groundstate

Tags: condensed-matter, hilbert-space, many-body, second-quantization, ground-state

Assume that I have a tight binding model given in second quantized form as follows;
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_i f_i^{\dagger}f_i + t \sum_{i,j} f_i^{\dagger}f_j 
\end{equation}
In real space, respective eigenvectors of the spectrum of the Hamiltonian can be written in the following form,
\begin{equation}
|\lambda> = \sum_i \alpha_i^\lambda f_i^{\dagger} |vac>
\end{equation}
Where I believe $\alpha_i^\lambda$ are the amplitudes of the probability of finding the particle at i'th lattice site.
I would like to put non-interacting fermions in my lattice at zero temperature. The ground state will consist of filled the lowest states up to a chemical potential. If we define $c_\lambda^\dagger = \sum_i \alpha_i^\lambda f_i^{\dagger}$, the ground state will look like this
\begin{equation}
|GS> = \prod_\lambda^\mu c_\lambda^\dagger |0>
\end{equation}

The problem that I face is that I $c_\lambda$ operator acts on the Fock space of the vacuum and I cannot relate it to the space the $f_i$ operator is acting on. The Fock space is given in number basis and tells how many electrons are there in the given state. In the fermionic case, if I assume spin-orbit coupling, each state can host 1 fermion. Further the index of the n_i in the Fock state $|n_1, n_2, ..., n_m>$ will tell us whether n_i'th eigenstate of the TB Hamiltonian is filled or not. Then how can I calculate the expectation value of <$f_i^\dagger f_j$> on my above-described ground state?

Comment: Hint: Express the $f_j$s in terms of the $c_\lambda$s and then make use of the fact that $\langle \mathrm{GS}|c_\lambda^\dagger c_{\lambda^\prime}|\mathrm{GS}\rangle = \delta_{\lambda,\lambda^\prime}$ if $\lambda$ is occupied at all (I don't fully understand your notation regarding $\mu$, but I think it is clear what I mean in any case)--else it is vanishing anyway.

Comment: @TobiasFünke How can I express $f_j$ in terms of $c_\lambda$ as it was given the other way around

Comment: After you diagonalize H, you've already known how $c^\dagger_\lambda$ is expressed in term of $f^\dagger_j$ by $c_\lambda^\dagger = \sum_i \alpha_i^\lambda f_i^{\dagger}$, where $\alpha_i^\lambda$ should be a unitary matrix. The inverse of this unitary transformation is just $f^\dagger_j = \sum_\lambda \alpha^{\lambda *}_j c^\dagger_\lambda$.